Unable to boot Ubuntu 24.04 - Failed to start nvidia-persistenced.service
I did system update lastly. After that I am not able to boot with error Failed to start nvidia-persistenced.service.
I have found possible solution to reinstall driver with
using sudo apt-get purge nvidia* and sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
problem is that I do not know how to get to GRUB. With Esc I get to HP bootup menu where I can select USB or disk for boot.
So I figured out how to get to GRUB to be able enter recovery mode. On HP laptop Esc enters to HP menu then just continue and press Esc one more time. But anyway I was unable to fix my problem with boot –

I have tried to run sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall in recovery mode for second time and problem solved.
